# Java decompiler. How work?

Tags: java, algorithm, decompiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a de-compiler how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902074/what-is-a-de-compiler-how-does-it-work)

In stackoverflow I can find many questions about java decompilers. But, in general cases, users look on decompiler as on tools and no more.

For me, it's interesting to learn how a decompiler works? 
What is the algorithm used for classic decompilers? Who does know?
Any articles about this?

Comment: seriously?  http://bit.ly/zKyfmk - Let me google that for you.

Comment: did you even try to google it ?